# React Navigation animation still showing when animationEnabled prop is set to false

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I was creating a bottom tab bar without using the react-native-navigation built-in one and I wanted to disable the left and right slide animation. First I tried using the animationEnabled prop but it does not seem to do anything. I also tried to use timing and set the duration to 0 but it hasn't worked either. What am I doing wrong?

RootStack.js

```
// import react navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

// import screens
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import Signup from '../screens/Signup';
import Welcome from '../screens/Welcome';
import AccountScreen from '../screens/AccountScreen';
import NewsScreen from '../screens/NewsScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import TrendingScreen from '../screens/TrendingScreen';
import TabBarComponent from '../components/TabBarComponent';



// Colors
import {Colors} from '../components/styles';
const{brand, darkLight, primary, tertiary } = Colors;

import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



    

const ArrowStack = () => {
    return(
        
        <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator
                    timingConfig={{
                        duration: 0,
                    }}
                    screenOptions={{
                        animationEnabled: false,
                        headerShown: true,
                        headerStyled: {
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                            elevation: 0
                        },
                        headerShadowVisible: false,
                        headerTransparent: true,
                        headerTitle: '',
                        headerLeftContainerStyle:{
                            paddingLeft:20
                        }


                    }}
                    initialRouteName="Login"
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}  />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome}  />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Trending" component={TrendingScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}


export default ArrowStack;
```

Welcome.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Pressable, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';




import TabBarComponent from '../components/TabBarComponent';

import{ 
    InnerContainer,
    PageTitle,
    SubTitle,
    StyledFormArea,
    Colors,
    StyledButton,
    ButtonText,
    Line,
    WelcomeContainer,
    WelcomeImage,
    Avatar,
    TabBarContainer,
    TabBar,
    TabBarInnerContainer
} from './../components/styles'

// import tabBarIcons
import Home from '../tabBarIcons/Home';
import News from '../tabBarIcons/News';
import Account from '../tabBarIcons/Account';
import Trending from '../tabBarIcons/Trending';
import Search from '../tabBarIcons/Search';

// Colors
const{brand, darkLight, primary} = Colors;


const Welcome = ({ navigation }) => {
    

    return(
        <>
            <StatusBar style="light"/>
            <InnerContainer>
                
                <WelcomeContainer>

                    <PageTitle welcome={true}>Welcome! Buddy</PageTitle>
                    <SubTitle welcome={true}>Olga Simpson</SubTitle>
                    <SubTitle welcome={true}>johndoe@email.com</SubTitle>

              
                    
                    <StyledFormArea>
                        
                        <Line />
                        <StyledButton onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate("Login");
                            }}>
                            <ButtonText>
                                Logout
                            </ButtonText>
                        </StyledButton>
                    
                    
                    </StyledFormArea>
                    <TabBarContainer>
        <TabBar>
            <TabBarInnerContainer>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("News");

            }}>
                <News/>

            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Account");

            }}>
                <Account />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Welcome");

            }}>
                <Home />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Trending");

            }}>
                <Trending />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Search");

            }}>
                <Search />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </TabBarInnerContainer>
        </TabBar>
    </TabBarContainer>
                

                
                </WelcomeContainer>
            </InnerContainer>
        </>
    );

}



export default Welcome;
```

NewsScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
// import tabBarIcons
import Home from '../tabBarIcons/Home';
import News from '../tabBarIcons/News';
import Account from '../tabBarIcons/Account';
import Trending from '../tabBarIcons/Trending';
import Search from '../tabBarIcons/Search';

import{ 
    InnerContainer,
    PageTitle,
    SubTitle,
    StyledFormArea,
    Colors,
    StyledButton,
    ButtonText,
    Line,
    WelcomeContainer,
    WelcomeImage,
    Avatar,
    TabBarContainer,
    TabBar,
    TabBarInnerContainer,
    ScreenContainer,
    TabBarContainerScreen
} from './../components/styles'

const NewsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
        <InnerContainer>
            <ScreenContainer> 
                <><View>
                    <Text>
                        News Screen
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <TabBarContainerScreen>
                        <TabBar>
                            <TabBarInnerContainer>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("News");

                                } }>
                                    <News />

                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Account");

                                } }>
                                    <Account />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Welcome");

                                } }>
                                    <Home />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Trending");

                                } }>
                                    <Trending />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Search");

                                } }>
                                    <Search />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </TabBarInnerContainer>
                        </TabBar>
                    </TabBarContainerScreen></>
            </ScreenContainer>
        </InnerContainer>
    );

}

export default NewsScreen;
```

AccountScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
// import tabBarIcons
import Home from '../tabBarIcons/Home';
import News from '../tabBarIcons/News';
import Account from '../tabBarIcons/Account';
import Trending from '../tabBarIcons/Trending';
import Search from '../tabBarIcons/Search';

import{ 
    InnerContainer,
    PageTitle,
    SubTitle,
    StyledFormArea,
    Colors,
    StyledButton,
    ButtonText,
    Line,
    WelcomeContainer,
    WelcomeImage,
    Avatar,
    TabBarContainer,
    TabBar,
    TabBarInnerContainer,
    ScreenContainer,
    TabBarContainerScreen
} from './../components/styles'

const AccountScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
        <InnerContainer>
            <ScreenContainer> 
                <><View>
                    <Text>
                        Account Screen
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <TabBarContainerScreen>
                        <TabBar>
                            <TabBarInnerContainer>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("News");

                                } }>
                                    <News />

                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Account");

                                } }>
                                    <Account />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Welcome");

                                } }>
                                    <Home />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Trending");

                                } }>
                                    <Trending />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Search");

                                } }>
                                    <Search />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </TabBarInnerContainer>
                        </TabBar>
                    </TabBarContainerScreen></>
            </ScreenContainer>
        </InnerContainer>
    );

}

export default AccountScreen;
```

SearchScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
// import tabBarIcons
import Home from '../tabBarIcons/Home';
import News from '../tabBarIcons/News';
import Account from '../tabBarIcons/Account';
import Trending from '../tabBarIcons/Trending';
import Search from '../tabBarIcons/Search';

import{ 
    InnerContainer,
    PageTitle,
    SubTitle,
    StyledFormArea,
    Colors,
    StyledButton,
    ButtonText,
    Line,
    WelcomeContainer,
    WelcomeImage,
    Avatar,
    TabBarContainer,
    TabBar,
    TabBarInnerContainer,
    ScreenContainer,
    TabBarContainerScreen
} from './../components/styles'

const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
        <InnerContainer>
            <WelcomeContainer> 
                <><View>
                    <Text>
                        Search Screen
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <TabBarContainerScreen>
                        <TabBar>
                            <TabBarInnerContainer>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("News");

                                } }>
                                    <News />

                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Account");

                                } }>
                                    <Account />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Welcome");

                                } }>
                                    <Home />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Trending");

                                } }>
                                    <Trending />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Search");

                                } }>
                                    <Search />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </TabBarInnerContainer>
                        </TabBar>
                    </TabBarContainerScreen></>
            </WelcomeContainer>
        </InnerContainer>
    );

}

export default SearchScreen;
```

TrendingScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
// import tabBarIcons
import Home from '../tabBarIcons/Home';
import News from '../tabBarIcons/News';
import Account from '../tabBarIcons/Account';
import Trending from '../tabBarIcons/Trending';
import Search from '../tabBarIcons/Search';

import{ 
    InnerContainer,
    PageTitle,
    SubTitle,
    StyledFormArea,
    Colors,
    StyledButton,
    ButtonText,
    Line,
    WelcomeContainer,
    WelcomeImage,
    Avatar,
    TabBarContainer,
    TabBar,
    TabBarInnerContainer,
    ScreenContainer,
    TabBarContainerScreen
} from './../components/styles'

const TrendingScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return(
        <InnerContainer>
            <ScreenContainer> 
                <><View>
                    <Text>
                        Trending Screen
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <TabBarContainerScreen>
                        <TabBar>
                            <TabBarInnerContainer>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("News");

                                } }>
                                    <News />

                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Account");

                                } }>
                                    <Account />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Welcome");

                                } }>
                                    <Home />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Trending");

                                } }>
                                    <Trending />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                    navigation.navigate("Search");

                                } }>
                                    <Search />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </TabBarInnerContainer>
                        </TabBar>
                    </TabBarContainerScreen></>
            </ScreenContainer>
        </InnerContainer>
    
    );

}

export default TrendingScreen;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frfr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "expo": "~43.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are using a NativeStackNavigator, you shouldn't use **animationEnabled** but **animation** instead.

List of supported values : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator#animation

```
options = {
    {
        animation: 'none',
    }
}
```